# Trying to resolve a gcc specific compilation error

Tags: c++

Here is a program I am trying to compile.

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    T foo() const
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A<T>
{
    using U = A<T>;
    T foo() const
    {
        return 2;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct D
{
    B<T> b;
    int foo() const
    {
        // using U = typename B<T>::U; // compilation succeeds if I uncomment this line
        return b.U::foo();
    }
};

int main()
{
    D<int> d;
    return d.foo();
}
```

I see different behaviour across gcc 9.2, clang 9.0.0 and icc19.0.1.
The program fails to compile with gcc giving an error `U has not been declared`, compiles fine with clang and has a non-trivial assembly with icc.
Why is the behaviour different across these compilers?

I tried reading [dependent_name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) but gave up since I couldn't follow it properly. From what little I understand, data member `b` inside struct `D` has a dependent type and `U` should have been resolved when the template is instantiated.

Compiled the above code with the above compilers on godbolt.org here: https://godbolt.org/z/n_Wl44. I used C++17 with -O3 flag. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Looks like 50/50 if you bring in all of the compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/F1JnWH

Comment: @TedLyngmo wow, that was neat. I didn't know about conformance viewer.

Comment: Noticed it myself just a few days ago. Really nice! But I suspect it's a little buggy. The colours don't always match the result etc.

Comment: I think this is just a bug in GCC. You should report it.

Comment: Gcc should find U because it is a dependent name in D and because of the rule of qualified member name look up: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.classref#4.

Comment: `using U = A<T>` is a *type alias* [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) that refers to a *type-id*, not to a member. So `B.U`  is an error.

Comment: @Ripi2 I don't think it is parsed that way. `U::foo` is a *qualified-name* which may be used as the right-hand side of a class member access operator. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @uneven_mark You're right, `:` has more precedence that `.`. Seems you picked the gcc error.

Comment: @Ripi2 I meant "*qualified-id*", not "*qualified-name*". I don't understand what you mean with "*Seems you picked the gcc error.*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`U` in `b.U::foo();` should be looked up during instantiation in the context of `B<T>` first, finding `using U = A<T>;`, so that `b.U::foo()` calls `foo()` defined in `A<T>`. [[basic.lookup.classref]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup#classref-4)

The lookup should be delayed until instantiation and no lookup at definition should happen, because `b` is dependent as its type depends on the template parameter `T`. [[temp.dep.expr]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep#expr-5)

Therefore this seems to be a bug in GCC. A very similar code example has been posted in [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85570), which demonstrates the same issue as far as I can tell. The bug is currently marked status "new".

As far as I can tell the other failing compilers shown in [the godbolt.org conformance view posted by @TedLyngmo](https://www.godbolt.org/z/F1JnWH) are derivatives of GCC, so it is not like independent compilers are disagreeing on this.